# "com.android.phone has stopped" after reboot, cured by changing Preferred Network -- how to make permanent

Tags: settings, samsung-galaxy-s-4, mobile-network

Phone info:

- "Google Play Edition" Galaxy S4 - GT-I9505ZWG
- Android 5.1, build number LMY470.S008.150802
- AT&T, Philadelphia

After rebooting the phone, I get the "com.android.phone has stopped" popup, and am unable to make calls or connect to the network.

I've been through the following steps to try to cure:

- Clear cache for all apps
- Clear data for "Phone" app (2 of them), as well as "CSC" and "com.phone.sec"

On a hunch, because there were issues last year with Google phones and AT&T support for LTE, I went into the "Preferred Network" settings and attempted to switch to 3G.

The first time doing this after reboot, touching the setting caused the settings app to exit. However, the signal strength meter then showed a signal, and I was able to make a call and connect to the Internet.

I then went back to this settings page, and was able to successfully change back and forth between 3G and LTE.

However, after rebooting, I was back in "com.android.phone has stopped" land.

It appears to be a settings issue, but which setting? And how to change? Is there a particular app that I should clear data for?

I don't want to do a factory reset, especially since I have a work-around.

If necessary, I can get logcat output. However I'd want a pointer to the specific output required, rather than dumping the whole mess into the question.